# Can reach WebAPI from Postman but not Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, http, post, service

**Goal**: I am trying to update a column in a row in a database table from an Angular app.

**Problem**:
The service in the Angular has the data from the parameters, and the URL for the WebAPI endpoint looks correct, but the angular service call is getting to the catchError(this.handleError) -- but I don't actually see an error.

**What ive tried**
I've tested the endpoint from Postman. It works from there. But the service call in Angular is not reaching the endpoint. When I use devtools debugger I don't see any information in the handleError. How can I see this?

In Network tab, the Headers subtab just shows Request URL: http://localhost:1789/api/V/UpdateENotes

**Console errors**:

- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
  (Not Found) :1789/api/V/UpdateENotes:1
- Backend returned
  code 404, body was: [object Object] v.service.ts:567

**myService.ts:**

```
public UpdateENotes(visitID: number, eNotes: string): Observable<ResponseDTO>
{
  let url = environment.API_URL + '/api/V/UpdateENotes';

  let Params = new HttpParams();
  Params = Params.append('vID', vID.toString());
  Params = Params.append('eNotes', eNotes);

  return this.http.post<ResponseDTO>(url,null, {params: Params}).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

**WebAPI controller:**

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(ResponseDTO))]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/V/UpdateENotes")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateENotes(int vID, string eNotes)
    {
        try
        {
            ResponseDTO response = VManager.UpdateENotes(db,vID, eNotes);
            return await Task.FromResult(Ok(response));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there anything on the browser's development console?  A CORS error for example?

Comment: @David    **Console errors**:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) :1789/api/V/UpdateENotes:1          
Backend returned code 404, body was: [object Object] v.service.ts:567

Comment: Well, 404 Not Found means the server-side resource was not found.  In the browser's debugging tools, what is the full and complete URL being requested in this operation?  When you test in Postman, what is the full and complete URL being used?

Comment: @David Postman is http://localhost:1789/api/V/UpdateENotes?vID=12&eNotes=PostmanTHREE   . In the Headers subtab of the Network tab in Chrome devtools it shows Request URL without any of the params that are in the code : http://localhost:1789/api/V/UpdateENotes

Comment: The Postman URL has query string parameters, is it a GET or a POST?  Just to test, what if you manually include the query string parameters on the URL in the JavaScript code as well so it matches exactly?